# Reset data on click for a different controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have two divs - the first contains the second. The contained div has its own controller. When I click an icon button in the container, I change a variable which then affects the visibility of the contained div.

It looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="BarController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-2 page-title">My Page</div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <span class="actions">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-download fa-inverse" tooltip="Download"
                       ng-click="showSecondaryBar=!showSecondaryBar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="download navbar download-in download-out"
         ng-class="{'myhidden': !showSecondaryBar}"
         ng-cloak>
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 form-inline form-group" ng-controller="TagsController">
            <div class="download-label col-lg-6">
            <label>Download by tags:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="download-tags col-lg-6">
            <tags-input class="bootstrap" spellcheck="false" min-length="1" ng-model="tags" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
                <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length="1" load-on-down-arrow="true"
                               load-on-focus="true" max-results-to-show="5"
                               highlight-matched-text="false"></auto-complete>
            </tags-input>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<tags-input>` is taken from [ng-tags-input](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) and I would like to reset the tags that were already typed to it whenever the icon button is clicked (which changes the visilibyt of the div that contains the ng-tags-input).

Problem is, because I have the `TagsController` which contains the data (`tags`) and this data is not visible in the `BarController`, I'm not sure how I can reset the `tags` array to become empty.

I thought of using a service but it fills like too much of a coupling. I would prefer to have a function in `TagsController` which is called upon click. But I can't figure out how to do it from another controller

Comment: You're essentially trying to share stuff between two controllers. Service is your best take.

Comment: @TechMa9iac - That's what I started with. Thing is, the TagsController is not always coupled to the BarController. It can be used in other places that should be reset upon clicking this button. This fills like to tight-coupling, doesn't it?

Comment: @TechMa9iac - Bascially what I would really want is for TagsController to have some 'reset' method that I can call from another controller. I realize there's no direct way of doing it but I'm looking for a way that is not a service to do it. Using a service would make query the service to figure out if the TagsController needs to change instead of having some trigger that directly changes it. Sort of pull vs push. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$broadcast` on $rootScope to send an event to `TagsController`. So `TagsController` can receive this event by registering an event listener for it. See following example.

Refer to `$rootScope` [API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ParentController', function($rootScope) {
    var parentCtrl = this;
  parentCtrl.someFlag = true;
  
  parentCtrl.changeFlag = function() {
    parentCtrl.someFlag = !parentCtrl.somFlag;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('resettags', {'defaultTags': 'whatever_tag'});
  }
  })
.controller('ChildController', function($rootScope){
    var childCtrl = this;
    childCtrl.tags = "Some tags entered by user";
  $rootScope.$on('resettags', function(event, args) {
      
      childCtrl.tags = args.defaultTags;
    });
  });
```

```css
.myHidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div id="main" ng-controller="ParentController as parentCtrl">
      <button type="button" ng-click="parentCtrl.changeFlag()">Toggle</button>
      <div ng-class="{'myHidden' : !parentCtrl.someFlag}">
        <div ng-controller="ChildController as childCtrl">
              <h1>{{childCtrl.tags}}</h1>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right you have to use a service.
Why don't you use a broadcast as your TagsController is included in BarController?

You can include a scope.broadcast("Event") in BarController

Then a "on" listener on TagsController who will  reset the tags array when "Event" Occur.

I would personnaly to this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope